# LDAP аутентификация

Tags: c#, ldap

С клиента на сервер нужно передать данные о доменном пользователе под которым запущено приложение. Environment.UserName не подходит, так как пользователь админ на своем компьютере и может создать своего пользователя с тем же именем. Как быть уверенным что запустил приложение именно тот пользователь, который прописан в LDAP?

Comment: Пользователь может быть хоть кем на своем компьютере, но у него не должно быть права создавать доменные учетные записи.

Comment: @tym32167 так и возникает вопрос как его отличить. Имя будет тем же самым, рабочую группу можно назвать как и домен

Comment: в смысле, сначала проверить, подключена ли [машина к домену](https://stackoverflow.com/q/926227/312041), потом [проверить юзера](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12710355/312041)?

Comment: Вы же уже задавали похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870560/ , и там в ответе есть код проверки, вошел ли пользователь в заданный домен. Только учтите, что 100% гарантий в плане безопасности это не дает, ведь пользователь-администратор может поднять фальшивый домен с таким же именем на виртуалке. Реальная аутентификация должна быть на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Доменное имя пользователя содержится в `User.Identity.Name`.
Если приложение на IIS (ASP.NET MVC), то в нем нужно установить тип аутентификации Windows и отключить анонимную.
Если приложение на .NET Core, то у метода или всего контроллера должен быть установлен атрибут `[Authorize]`.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string userName = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я хотел показать, что в переменной. Но вы правы, исправлю.